# window.location.href adds path in URL

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm trying to redirect from my axios call, but window.location.href redirects me in wrong place. Somehow it inserts directory path into url: https://my_site.com/prod/public/en/index
/prod/public is the path where my project is located

This happens only in production server. In development environment and in test server, everything is fine. Also I found out that this is happen only when I'm adding index page, for example /en/index  if I put /en/product_name it forks fine?!?!?

My code:

```
return axios
    .put(`/lang/` + code)
    .then(response => {
         console.log(response.data);  // en/index
         console.log(location.href);  // https://my_site.com
         window.location.href = "/" + response.data; // redirects me to: https://my_site.com/prod/public/en/index 
     })
```

I'm expecting to go to: https://my_site.com/en/index instead of https://my_site.com/prod/public/en/index

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: instead of href use replace like `location.replace('/en/index')`

Comment: @AnilTalla — Why? That will do exactly the same thing except it will replace the current entry in the history instead of appending after it.

Comment: @AnilTalla, this does not work, it still adds /prod/public/

Comment: @Quentin, there is no redirects. Its index page. And even if I have, from where could I get /prod/public ??? It's very strange...

Answer (score 2):

**The problem:**

`window.location.href= "/" + response.data;` redirects to the root of your page + `en/index`. In your case the root is `/prod/public`, so this is added to / the starting point of the url.

**The solution**

You could use location.origin + response.data instead in case you are on a different sub directory

```js
return axios
    .put(`/lang/` + code)
    .then(response => {
         console.log(response.data);  // en/index
         console.log(location.origin);  // https://my_site.com
         var new_location = location.origin+ "/" + response.data;
         console.log('new location is:' new_location); // to test if the url here is the same as the 1 you get directed to
window.location.href = new_location;
 // redirects me to: https://my_site.com/en/index 
     })
```

Comment: _“In your case the root is `/prod/public`”_ - we are talking about the root from the _client_ perspective here, and that is always `/`. Assigning `/foo/bar` to location.href can only ever lead you to `http(s)://example.com/foo/bar`, and not anywhere else with additional path components appearing out of thin air.

Comment: @user2870907  window.location.href = location.origin + "/" + response.data;  gives me the same result: https://my_site.com/prod/public/en/index

Comment: @misorude, but it does exactly that. I found that it does that only on /en/index/  if I put /en/product_name/   it works...

Comment: @dust_bg that “it” _does_ that, doesn’t mean it’s this part of the code’s _fault_. You said there were no redirects, but if you actually inspect this in your browser dev tools network panel, I’d bet there is a request for `/en/index` first.

Comment: @dust_bg and if you try it without window.location.href, aka, assigning location.origin + "/" + response.data to a variable and trying to log this variable? As misorude indicated, there might be a ridirect happening, logging this variable can see if this is indeed the case.

Comment: @misorude, There is only one redirect (301) in first line to /en/index/

Comment: Do you mean a redirect _to_ `/en/index/`, or _from_ there? Presumably the latter, and presumably to `/prod/public/en/index/`; please show a screenshot if otherwise.

Comment: @user2870907, if I print location.origin + "/" + response.data  it gives me correct URL! I have to comment  window.location.href = location.origin + "/" + response.data;  to check log. But if I uncomment it it redirects me to https://my_site.com/prod/public/en/index ?!?!?

Comment: @dust_bg that sounds like you are getting redirected by something else (like some host setting on your production server or something like switcheroo (chrome plugin)) If you try to access the currect URL directly in your production environement, are you getting redirected then?

Comment: @misorude, result is : 301 : GET : my_site.com : /en/index : document : html : etc ... there is no other redirects, there are no /prod/public/ except in URL box (/prod/public/en/index/)

Comment: @user2870907, no, I get correct page without redirects

Comment: If there wasn’t an actual HTTP redirect, then how would you get to see it say “301” anywhere in the first place …? Sure you aren’t misinterpreting what you are seeing?

Comment: _“there are no /prod/public/ except in URL box (/prod/public/en/index/)”_ - well in theory, it could be client-side JavaScript using the History API to manipulate what you see in the address bar (that would be a “cosmetic” change without any actual redirect in the background) - but that doesn’t happen on its own and by accident either, plus this would still need to know about the `/prod/public` part from somewhere in the first place.)

Comment: @misorude, could it be from .htaccess file? There I have RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/prod/public/
RewriteRule (.*) /prod/public/$1

Comment: could be indeed

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/prod/public/  
RewriteRule (.*) /prod/public/$1
```

I still don't know why it puts /prod/public/ only in that route but... I resolved the problem.

Thanks to all you guys!